# фильтр по колонке созданной при запросе

Tags: sql, запрос

Не могу понять что я делаю не так

```
SELECT *, (`get` /  `set`) AS  `perc`
FROM  `torgovl` 
WHERE  `perc` > '1.01'
```

получаю ошибку

```
 Unknown column 'perc' in 'where clause'
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: В вашей таблице нет колонки с таким именем, по крайней мере маленькими буквами. А то что вы обозвали выражение `get/set` таким именем ни о чем никому не говорит, потому что фраза select выполняется после фразы where. Так что в where явно пишите get/set > 1.01

Comment: @Mike так я ее создаю при селекте. Или как фильтровать по виртуальной колонке?

Comment: по виртуальной никак, явно повторяйте выражение. ну или на крайний случай оберните запрос в еще один select, в нем эти имена уже будут доступны

Comment: @Mike, хм. Интерестно. раньше так писал - работало

Comment: не может быть (В MySQL). вот если вы в gaving или order by это писали - то там оно работает, потому что эти предложения выполняются после select

Comment: @Mike, точно помню что так писал, года два назад. Возможно в последних версиях mysql что то поменяли

Comment: Маловероятно, такое вообще мало какие СУБД поддерживают. Я даже не совсем уверен, что хоть одна поддерживает. Сомневаюсь только по поводу SQLite, она очень странные вещи позволяет, вроде голых колонок в having, это примерно из той же оперы

Answer (score 0):

`perc` является синонимом, синонимы не разрешено использовать с инструкцией where.
Обойти это можно через with или так:
SELECT *
from (
SELECT *, (`get` /  `set`) AS  `perc`
FROM  `torgovl` ) p
WHERE  p.perc > 1.01